# SSIS Foreach loop through text files with "crosswlk" in the name

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

In my Foreach loop I only want to process files that have **crosswlk** in the filename.  Unfortunately this is in the middle of the filename and I can't do **crosswlk.pgp**.

I have Googled this a bunch and most solutions say to do some C# in a script task to accomplish this.  It seems like I should be able to do this in the Foreach container, maybe in the Collection area with Expressions.  But I'm having troubles finding any information about the various Properties in the Property Expressions Editor.  What's the difference between the Name, `FileSpec` and `FileNameRetrieval` properties?

I thought I could do something like:

```
Property: Name
Expression: `FINDSTRING(@[User::SourceFilename],"crosswlk",1) > 0`
```

To me that's saying only process files where the filename has **crosswlk** in it.  But that's not working.  I did notice the word **crosswlk** always starts at the 13th character in the filename so I tried using substring, but no luck there either.

Is there a way to do filter the filenames this (or another) way, or is using C# the only way?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should be able to use wildcards in the Files field.

> Use wildcard characters (*) to specify the files to include in the
>   collection. For example, to include files with names that contain
>   “abc”, use the following filter: *abc*.

So, you should be able to use something like this: `*crosswlk*`

See here for more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container#enumerator-dynamic-options

Comment: I didn't think that would work because you can't do that in windows explorer.  Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is too hard to craft a usable wildcard then one option that might be of use is to use a FOREACH ADO Enumerator. First you "fill" a recordset Object Variable with all the filenames you want then you can loop through this.
You can fill the recordset object through a Script Task and use C# system.IO for interrogating the filesystem.
 This is a handy way if you need to tightly control what files are processed (eg to prevent test files being loaded)